# phonegap parse as backend to save camera picture cant work

Tags: javascript, cordova, parse-platform

**app.js**

```js
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
Parse.initialize("Bsx4lKtDVM36WIXgtrh3VElVNkJb9MRi6VJ8zl5L", "obSiqq5y7GV1SHfRveojFv5HllO3EJcdf0iValSl");
function init() {


    //Use from Camera
   
    //Use from Library
    document.querySelector("#usePicture").addEventListener("touchend", function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(gotPic, onFail, { 
            quality: 50,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });

    });

    
    function gotPic(data) {
       var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", {base64:data});
            parseFile.save().then(function() {
                navigator.notification.alert("Got it!", null);
                console.log("Ok");
                console.log(arguments.toString());
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("Error");
                console.log(error);
            });
        
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }   

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
        <style>
        button {
            width: 90%;
        }
        body {
            margin-top: 50px;
        }
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 250px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <img id="myImage">

    <button id="usePicture">Use Picture</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.15.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code is the `main.html` file the problem is when I run the app on my phone I able to click the button and select image from gallery but after that it unable to upload it to parse and there are no success message reply can you guys help me out to check what is wrong

Comment: You have to whitelisten every external url.

Comment: ya i have whitelisten all

Comment: What does the inspector say about outgoing traffic?

Comment: it can work alrdy it pointed out alert successful but i dont know how to create a class for it to insert can you help me out?